# @Resource dataSource mappedName - overriding to test in non JNDI env

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jndi, spring-test

I have an existing service bean which we deployed in Jboss. Unfortunatly it's dataSource reference is configured to inject the datasource reference via the "mappedName" lookup of the JNDI Service.

```
@Resource(name = "dataSource", mappedName = "java:/OracleDS")
private DataSource dataSource = null;
```

I want to test the bean in a non JNDI env. I expected to get this exception when i run in a non JNDI env.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'myService': Injection of resource fields failed; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean 
definition with name 'java:/OracleDS' defined in JNDI environment: JNDI lookup 
failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to 
specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, 
or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

I realise the quickest way to fix this is to dropped the mappedName restriction, since then the production or test spring context can define the datasource. But in the case that i can't do this. Is there a way to define an InitialContext via a test spring context to avoid the exception above.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more reading on [SimpleNamingContextBuilder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.html) and came up with this context setup for my test case. The trick being to use the MethodInvokingFactoryBean to ensure the bind() method is called.

```
<bean id="jndiContext" class="org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContextBuilder" factory-method="emptyActivatedContextBuilder"/>

<bean id="invokingFactoryBean"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref local="jndiContext" />
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>bind</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>java:/OracleDS</value>
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${datasource.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${datasource.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${datasource.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}" />
</bean>
```